# Integrate Git Support Branch to master

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have the following scenario in my job and I can't think a way of handling it so I would like to ask for some help.

1. We are following the git flow for the Core features of the product
2. We have multiple lines of releases that all are created as branches from master. What I mean is that for every client we get a version of the Core product (at the moment we start) and extend it to the clients needs.
3. At some points we want to integrate all the changes that have happened from the Core Product.
4. We do that by merging the changes from master to every branch.

**What I want to ask is the following case:**

1. We want to integrate from a previous version of the master. Let's say 1.3 while the master is in 1.5.
2. We find a bug in that tagged version.

Now we can fix it in the client branch and complete the integration, and add that fix to the current master (1.5) and be over with it.

However it would be very helpful to "inject" this fix into the 1.3 version of the master. This way anyone else trying to integrate this version would already have the fix.

Now from my point of view this thought kind of objects with the hole concept of numbering forward the version control but I think it would really help in some cases so I wanted to ask if anyone handles it somehow or if there is a git process for that, that I have missed.

I have seen the Git flow for [Support Branches and Hotfixes](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/git-branching-strategies/gitflow-examples/) but these branches don't cover my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your situation, I suggest you **merged the client branch which had bug fixed into `master` branch** (not the old version like 1.3) **and rebase other client branches on the top of latest `master` branch**.

Let’s illustrate why "inject" the fix from the client branch to an older version of `master` branch is not suggest.

Assume the commit history of the git repo as below. Client1~4 are the client branches created from `master` branch, and commit `A` is for version `1.3`, commit `C` is for version `1.5` on `master` branch. And there has bug fixed on `client1` branch.

```
          F---G client2         J---K client4
         /                     /
…---P---A-----------------B---C  master
         \                 \
          D---E client1     H---I client3
```

If you inject the fix in commit `A` (change the history commit on `master` branch), then it will cause the rebased `master` divided from the original `master` branch. The commands to inject fix into commit `A` and rebase `master` branch as below:

```
git checkout -b temp <commit P>
git merge client --squash
git rebase --onto temp <commit A> master
git branch -D temp
```

Then the commit history will be (the client branches which created from the original master branch are not on the rebased `master` branch now, and the existing client branches actually not contain the bug fixed changes):

```
          F---G client2         J---K client4
         /                     /
…---P---A-----------------B---C 
     \   \                 \
      \   D---E client1     H---I client3
       \
        A'---B'---C'  master
```

The correct way should **merge `client1` branch into `master` branch, and then rebasing other existing client branches on the top of `master` branch**. Detail steps as below:

#### 1.   Merge client1 branch into master branch

Execute below commands to merge `client1` into `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
git merge client1
git push origin master
```

Then the commit history will be (`M` is the merge commit):

```
          F---G client2         J---K client4
         /                     /
…---P---A-----------------B---C---------------M  master
         \                 \                 /
          \                 H---I client3   /
           \                               /
            ----------------------D-------E client1
```

#### 2.   Rebasing other existing client branches on the top of the master branch

To rebase other client branch on the top of the `master` branch, just need to execute `git pull origin master --rebase` on the client branches separately:

```
# rebase client2 branch
git checkout client2
git pull origin master --rebase
# rebase client3 branch
git checkout client3
git pull origin master --rebase
# rebase client4 branch
git checkout client4
git pull origin master --rebase
```

Then the commit history will be:

```
                        J'---K' client4     
                       /                         
                      F'---G' client2
                     /
…---P---A---B---C---M  master
         \         / \      
          D-------E   H'---I' client3
```

Now all the existing client branches contains the changes for bug fixed. And if new client branches are created, they will also contain the changes for the bug fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> However it would be very helpful to "inject" this fix into the 1.3 version of the master. This way anyone else trying to integrate this version would already have the fix.

For that, you need to:

- create a branch `master1.3`, starting from the tag 1.3 done on `master`, in which you apply that fix;
- rebase your 1.3 release branches (one per client) on top of the new `master1.3` branch.

The OP suggests:

> I would like to rebase somehow (not exactly rebase because I really don't know what might happen) the `master` pipeline.
>   So that from now every other dev that wants to integrate the 1.3, 1.4 and every following until the 1.5 to get it from master.

That would imply inserting the fix after the 1.3 commit, and applying the rest (1.4, 1.5): that is possible with a rebase interactive (`git rebase -i`), but way too problematic, as it would change the history of a common branch, used by everybody.

Hence my "1.3 hotfix" branch approach.

The other option is certainly to "add that fix to the current master (1.5) and be over with it.": I would not recommend messing with the commit history of `master`.

Comment: I would like to rebase somehow (not exactly rebase because I really don't know what might happen) the master pipeline. So that from now every other dev that wants to integrate the 1.3, 1.4 and every following until the 1.5 to get it from master. That was kind of the point of the question.

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis I have edited my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To be honest from what I have searched I was afraid that this would be the case. I will leave for a little more the question in case someone has anything more to suggest, :)